# (iphone) maintaining CGContextRef or CGLayerRef takes up less memory than UIImage?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgcontext

I need to work with many images, and I can't hold all of them as UIImage in memory because they are too big.
I also need to change colors of image and merge them on the fly.
Creating UIImage from underlying NSData, change color, and combine them when you can't have many images on memory is fairly slow. (as far as I can get)

I thought maybe I can store underlying CGLayerRef(for image that will be combined) and CGContextRef(the resulting combined image).

I am new to drawing world, and not sure if CGLayerRef or CGContextRef is smaller in memory than UIImage itself.
I recently heard that w*h image takes up w*h*4 bytes in memory.
Does CGLayerRef or CGContextRef also take up that much memory?

Thank you

- edit

Following is the strategy I'm thinking of to lower memory usage, and computing time.

```
CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(self.bitmapContext, self.frame.size, NULL);
CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);  
CGContextDrawImage(layerContext, self.bounds, image.CGImage);  
store 'layer' somewhere.  
possibly destroy layerContext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory usage of an image is almost entirely taken up in the bitmap. Whether you use `UIImage` or `CGImageRef` or something else, that won't change. The bitmap is still in memory.

Comment: ah thanks, since I need layerContext(which is bitmap) from layer to draw something onto it, I guess maintaining layer won't help me as far as memory goes either. Am I correct?

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, that's correct. As long as the bitmap is in memory, you'll see roughly the same memory usage.

Comment: one more question, I see people don't create layer's context, they just create layer with CGLayerCreateWithContext.  Does that mean layer's context is automatically created and takes up about the same memory even when nothing is drawn onto it for every layer created? see my edit for layer related code

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the CGLayer APIs, but I do believe you're correct and the CGLayer creates its own context. I don't know if it takes up memory before you draw into it, but I wouldn't be surprised.